# CSS3 Background Plus Transparency Without Images

Tags: css

I have a solid background color on a button, and I'm looking for some CSS(3?) that would overlay a semi-transparent white on top of the color, but only on the top 50% of it.  I'm looking for a non-gradient, non-image-based shine effect.

How can this be accomplished without using an image?  It's ok if the solution doesn't support older browsers.

**EDIT:**  bookcasey's answer below seems to work except the font is also made transparent...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:30px;
    background: salmon;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight:bold;
}

a:before
{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
</style>
</html>
<body>

<div>
    <a href="#">Test Link</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: what's wrong with using a gradient? that seems to be the obvious solution.

Comment: What research effort have you already made?

Comment: May not necessarily address your question, but this is a handy CSS3 tool: http://css3generator.com/

Comment: For the record, I have done research, and all I was able to find was gradients (I think of gradients as blending from one color to the next, but this isn't what I want) or image-based solutions which I'd rather not implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an absolutely positioned pseudo element on a relative parent.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E6FhW/)

```
a {display: block; width: 100px; height: 50px; background: salmon; position: relative;}
a:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Another, completely different technique (mentioned, but not explained in the comments) is the use of CSS3 gradients with a hard color stop.

```
a {display: block; width: 100px; height: 50px; position: relative;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5))), salmon;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%), salmon;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%), salmon;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%), salmon;
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%), salmon;}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DuMt8/)

Comment: Thanks - this actually works better since it doesn't also gray out the text inside the link